# How to add column to wp_post table in database?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a database named **event-listing-db** which contains a table **wp_posts**. Also i have a function for creating a form with method post with the following structure:

```
function ru_meta_callback() {
    wp_nonce_field(basename(__FILE__), 'ru_jobs_nonce ');
    ?>
    <form method="POST">
        <div>
            <div class="meta-row">
                <div class="meta-th">
                    <label for="date_listed" class="ru-row-title">Event Date</label>
                </div>
                <div class="meta-td">
                    <input type="text" name="event_date" id="event_date" value=""/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="meta-row">
                <div class="meta-th">
                    <label for="event_location" class="ru-row-title">Event Location</label>
                </div>
                <div class="meta-td">
                    <input type="text" name="event_location" id="event_location" value=""/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Add Event">
        </div>
    </form>
    <?php
}
```

When I submit the form only the **post_title** column is filling. My question is: How can I create columns for **event_date** and **event_location** and fill'em when the data is submitted and save the new columns along with the original post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to add a new column to the `wp_posts` table. But you can add a new meta for the post. If you want to add the field in the admin panel for the new field you want. You can use the [add_meta_box](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/) to add a new meta box for post edit screen and then use the [update_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/) on the `save_post` hook. Hope that helps.

> The meta fields can be used in the `WP_Query` in the `meta_query` index. But you can't use the custom field added to the `wp_posts` table to filter or search for the posts with the new meta added to the posts.

Comment: You don't have to use the `<form>` to add the new fields, It will conflict with the form WP is using to show all the fields.

Answer (score 1):

You have few options to have additional data to your post,
 -> You can use hooks to add additional fields like here, [WordPress - Add extra column to wp_posts, and post to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305116/wordpress-add-extra-column-to-wp-posts-and-post-to-it)
 -> You can make use of custom fields to add additional data to your post. And there is a good plugin too for this, https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/. 
 -> You can use the wp_postmeta table too to save your additional data for your post

Comment: Can you give me an example with my current form. I readed this topic and still not understand