# WordPress - Add 3 extra column to wp_posts, and post to it

Tags: wordpress, field

I am trying to add 3 extra field in my Add Post or Add Page, where I insert the value of that field into a manually added column added in the wp_posts table in the database.

I know that I can use Custom Field Templates, but the problem is that these custom fields insert the values into wp_postmeta and not wp_post, and I need everything for the single post in the same table.

what exactly code i have to use that my column field appear in wp-post page for example i add 3 column as:  my_field & my_field1 & my_field2 (these are text field)

there is answer for this question in the below link but it does not work on WordPress 5.1 
[WordPress - Add extra column to wp_posts, and post to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305116/wordpress-add-extra-column-to-wp-posts-and-post-to-it?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Just curious WHY you need to have the information in the `wp_post` table and not `wp_postmeta`?

Comment: Yeah, Why? this is a no no.

Comment: as i said in the above: I need everything for the single post in the same table.